# Attach a Study/ Strategy to a Tradingview Drawing Tool in

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am using Tradingview Pinescript 4.0 My question revolves around this link here:[Tradingview 4.0 Selective Alert Calls](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Alerts.html#using-selective-alert-calls) I also found info here: [TradingView Pine Script Tutorial 20 - Custom Alert Messages With alertcondition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAGMpWnjF3k&t=19s)

Basically, I wanted to create an Alert on a Trend Line. In the link above it appears that this portion of the code:

```
xUp = crossover( r, 50)
xDn = crossunder(r, 50)
```

is acting like some kind of `resistance/support line` (as actions will take place if Price goes above or below this "line"). What I would like to do is substitute "r" for the value under the "Coordinates" tab of a `Drawing Tool` (the one below - **PICTURE #1** - is showing the value from a `Horizontal Ray`). So, the code above would be something like the 2 lines below. **GOAL**: to be able to **specify a support/resistance line directly in an Alert** instead of hoping the the RSI calculation will hit it.

```
xUp = crossover( close, 50427.5 )
xDn = crossunder(close, 50427.5 )
```

The only way I can think of to "get this value in" is to do something like

```
crossover_val = input( title="Enter Level for Support/Resistance Line")
```

as part of the "input" section. But - my thoughts are that there must be a better way. My first thought was to attach it to the Drawing Tool ( ex: `Horizontal Ray, Trend Line, Horizontal Line`, etc.) using the regular Alert functionality. Unfortunately, there is no place where one can enter the name of a `Strategy` or `Study`.

So, can this be done? Is it possible to connect a Strategy or Study to a Drawing Tool? If so, how?

TIA

**PICTURE #1**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pine scripts have no visibility on the chart's drawings, so no, it's not possible to use a hand-drawn object's coordinates in a script.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense -